# Contents inserted by Javascript is not catching up the styles

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-mobile

Consider the code given at the end, which makes use of jQuery Mobile to enhance buttons.

The first button (original button) appears when page loads:
[image]

The second button (inserted button) is inserted by clicking the yellow box:
[image]

The problem here is, the inserted button cannot catch up the CSS styles. This scenario is very common (and not specific to jQuery Mobile) when we work with AJAX, but I have never able to find a solution or workaround for this problem.

What can I do to enhance the inserted button with CSS styles?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>          

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function insert(){
                $("#result").html('<input type="button" value="Inserted button"/>');
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form>

            <p class="ui-body-e ui-corner-all" style="padding:5px" onclick="insert()">Click here to insert the button</p>

            <input type="button" value="Original button" />

            <div id="result">
                Button not inserted yet  
            </div>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you insert the button's html:

```
$("#result").html('<input type="button" value="Inserted button"/>');
```

You can call `.trigger('create')` on its container to invoke the jQuery-mobile renderer on its contents, so your line would look like this:

```
$("#result").html('<input type="button" value="Inserted button"/>').trigger('create');
```

Comment: didn't know about the `.trigger('create');` nice one ;)

Comment: Where can I find the related documentation in the jQuery Mobile site?

Comment: Thanks! Your answer works too, but in case you want to insert a large amount of html at once (more than just one element), triggering the create event is nice and simple. :)

Comment: documentation => [Initializing groups of dynamically-injected form elements](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/forms/docs-forms.html)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery mobile adds extra elements/classes to your objects. This happens onpage load.

When you insert extra buttons or other objects (list,...) the style needs to be applied again.

in this case you use after you inserted the button `$(_selector_for_new_button_).button();`

jQuery mobile applies the nice button style for you.